# python SIGTERM not work when I use multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pool, sigterm

Correct code as expected:
    from multiprocessing import Pool
    import signal
    import time
    import os

```
def consumer(i):
    while True:
        # print os.getpid()
        pass
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Here you go'

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
p = Pool(5)
p.map_async(consumer, [1 for i in range(5)])

while True:
    pass

p.terminate()
# p.close()
p.join()
```

==================================================

I have found the problem, when I use map function, the main func is blocked, and signal handler will be called only when map function is funished.
So, use "map_async" function is much more better to fix this problem.

Here is what I found:

A long-running calculation implemented purely in C (such as regular expression matching on a large body of text) may run uninterrupted for an arbitrary amount of time, regardless of any signals received. The Python signal handlers will be called when the calculation finishes.

==================================================

I wrote a program like the following, and I expect to exit/(like the program print string) in the program when I type "kill pid" in the terminal, but it not work. Is there any other strategy that block the SIGTERM get in the main func.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import signal
import time
import os

def consumer(i):
    while True:
        # print os.getpid()
        pass
def handler(signum, frame):
    print 'Here you go'

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
p = Pool(5)
p.map(consumer, [1 for i in range(5)])

p.terminate()
# p.close()
p.join()
```

Comment: You need to call `terminate` first, then `join`. Not vice versa.

Comment: I tried call terminate first , then join. But it seems not work for my question, but also thanks for your help. @noxdafox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [`map_async`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map_async) method as the `map` one blocks until results are not ready. Therefore, in your example the call to `terminate` is never reached.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct so other people can benefit from it then. :)